# Is the Grantmaking -> Funding Focus field a default in the non-profit version?

Tags: nonprofit-starter-pack

I am volunteering in the task of documenting and making recommendations for a non-profit SalesForce setup. Many hands worked on the setup and changes of SalesForce without documenting their decisions. So, I'm a little bit in the dark. In Accounts, there is this field in the Grantmaking section called Funding Focus. Is that a default field for a non-profit starter version?

[image: Grantmaking field in Accounts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Contact custom field list in Setup, look in the Installed Package column for the field to see if it's in a Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP) package.

FYI, your best resource for NPSP support is the Salesforce Foundation's Power of Us Hub here:  https://powerofus.force.com

You can login with your Salesforce ID and gain access to Chatter groups covering many aspects of the NPSP.  Foundation staff, consultants and non-profit organizations are all participants in the groups.

Comment: I think our whole task force may find this resource helpful. But you mention Nonprofit Success Pack and the settings call it a Nonprofit Starter Pack. What is the difference? Is it just a name change?

Comment: Salesforce changed the name last year or this year, so it used to be Starter Pack but now it's Success Pack.  Still the same thing though.